# Check if var is an URL in swift

Tags: swift, url

How can I test if a variable is an url?
What are the conditions to be an url?

Comment: how are you getting this variable?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know if a given string value represents a URL or do you want to know if a variable of type `Any` is actually an instance of a `URL` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test it with:

```
var maybeUrl = "http://is.this.an.url"

if let url = URL(string:maybeUrl) {
    // work with the url
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. That correct initializer would be `URL(string:)`

Comment: Note that this won’t work if the scheme `"http://"` is missing.  `“www.google.com”`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus - i corrected the answer. Btw: What is your connection to Geddy Lee?

Comment: Kk Just a Rush fan fore more than 30 years